# sqlfiddle & MySQL, not the same result with @variable

Tags: mysql

I try to figure out why MySQL doesn't get the same result than sqlfiddle, can someone help me to solve my request?

TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) UNIQUE,
  `name` varchar(20),
  `time` int(11),
  `points` int(11),
  `car` varchar(10),
  `date`date
);
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `name`, `time`, `points`, `car`, `date`) VALUES
  (1, 'Daniel', 55, 210, 'red', '2018-01-20'),
  (2, 'Daniel', 45, 250, 'green', '2018-01-21'),
  (3, 'Julie', 54, 220, 'red', '2018-01-19'),
  (4, 'Julie', 33, 150, 'yellow', '2018-01-22');
```

REQUEST

```
        SELECT *, @row_num, @prev_value, 
        @row_num := F(@prev_value=bla.name,@row_num+1,1) as RowNumber,
     @prev_value:=bla.name 
        FROM (SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY name, TEST.POINTS DESC, TEST.TIME ASC) bla,
SELECT @row_num := 1) x
```

[sqlfiddle result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5E5n6.png)

[MySQL result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwLeN.png)

Why @prev_value is always NULL ?